# SQL query Join with datetime inside

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to manage some data and retrieve a result I'm not able to do.

```
Table1
id int
idcat int (related to the table2)
tt varchar
dt datetime

Table2
idcat int
days int
```

what I need is to retrieve **ALL** `table1` record that are not older than days related to each `category` (`idcat`).

Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from Table1 a join Table2 b on a.idcat = b.idcat where DATEDIFF(NOW(), dt)<=b.days
```

should give you all records that are not older than days in each category

Comment: Thanks.I need to retreive all records not older than the number of days specified in each category. For Example category1 10 days, cat2 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether my below query will work but this is how the logic need to be implemented. I have modified my SQL Server Query to MySQL therefore I am not sure.

```
SELECT * from Table1 a join Table2 b on a.idcat = b.idcat where DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL b.days DAY)
```

You can use `DATE_ADD()` function try the below Query.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2008-12-15', INTERVAL b.days DAY)
```